# Finding the 2nd max key of linked list?

Tags: java, list

Please help me fix my code. Some cases work but I believe cases like `[9,1,2]` would not work because the first number is the largest in that case. I am not sure how to fix that in my code.

```
public Key secondMaxKey () {
    Node max = first;
    Node max_2nd = first;

    if (size() < 2) {
        return null;
    }

    for (Node x = first; x != null;x = x.next) {

        if (x.key.compareTo(max.key) == 1) {
            max_2nd = max;
            max = x;
        } else if (x.key.compareTo(max_2nd.key) == 1) {
            max_2nd = x;
        }
    }
    return max_2nd.key;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you first check the size then proceed with the algorithm.
A little change to yours here as we use the first two nodes to set the max and max_2 (depending on the values of these). Then we proceed as you did.
Check it out. Hope it helps

```
public Key secondMaxKey () {
            if(size() < 2){
                return null;
            }
            Node max = null;
            Node max_2 = null;

            Node second = first.next;

            if(first.key.compareTo(second.key) > 0){
                max = first;
                max_2 = second;
            }   else{
                max = second;
                max_2 = first;
            }

            for (Node x=second.next; x != null;x=x.next)
            {
                if (x.key.compareTo(max.key) > 0)
                {
                    max_2=max;
                    max=x;
                }
                else if ((x.key.compareTo(max_2.key) > 0)
                        && (x.key.compareTo(max.key) < 0))
                {
                    max_2=x;
                }
            }
            return  max_2.key;
        }
```

Comment: There were errors when using Iterator, also i believe I cant use that for class

Comment: There you go. Try now

Comment: It compiles correctly but the test is giving errors. in Remy's answer i have put the test code .Returned incorrect value K for case 2
Returned incorrect value H for case 3
Returned incorrect value X for case 5
Returned incorrect value S for case 7
Returned incorrect value Z for case 9
Done testing secondMax...some tests failed!

Comment: I have edited the 'else if' block. It was faulty indeed when it comes to checking for the second max.

Comment: This was the output from the updated code: Testing secondMax
Returned incorrect value K for case 2
Returned incorrect value H for case 3
Returned incorrect value X for case 5
Returned incorrect value S for case 7
Returned incorrect value Z for case 9
Done testing secondMax...some tests failed!

Comment: Ok your code is not 100% clear to me, but i am guessing that you should be comparing values of the entries, not keys. The key is only used in the return statement. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: honestly i have no idea i also dont understand the test code, thanks for the help though!

Comment: Just out of curiosity.. if you change the String answers[] to  { null, null, "K", "C", "A", "H", "K", "A", "X", "A" };  in the test2ndMAx method.. what will be the result of the test cases (running the above solution with values checks)?

Comment: Tried that and it says the method compareTo(Value) is undefined for the type Value

Comment: Ok, add the content of the LinkedListST (where i presume you placed the secondMaxKey method) and Node classes. Let see what they hold inside.

Comment: i added it to the main post

Comment: Ok, change the signature to 'public class LinkedListST<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value extends Comparable<Value>>'. Lets see what happens

Comment: i am not allowed to change that for class

Comment: Ok, the problem was that you were comparing using ==. It must be '< 0' and '> 0'. I have updated the code try now.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Key secondMaxKey() {
    if (this.size() <= 1)
        return null;
    if (this.size() == 2){
        if(first.key.compareTo(first.next.key) > 0){
            return first.next.key;
        }
    }
    Key max = first.key;
    Key secondMax = first.next.key;
    Node n = first;
    for (Node x = n.next; x != null; x = x.next) {
        if (x.key.compareTo(max) >= 0) {
            secondMax = max;
            max = x.key;
        } else if (x.key.compareTo(secondMax) > 0)
            secondMax = x.key;
    }
    return secondMax;
}
```

I believe your issue is with the implementation. particularly, setting the second max to the same temp Node as the max.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should initiate `max` and `max_2nd` with null and check if they are null in you if statements:

```
public Key secondMaxKey () {
    Node max = null;
    Node max_2nd = null;

    if (size() < 2) {
        return null;
    }

    for (Node x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
        if (max == null || x.val.compareTo(max.val) > 0) {
            max_2nd = max;
            max = x;
        } else if (max_2nd == null || x.val.compareTo(max_2nd.val) > 0) {
            max_2nd = x;
        }
    }

    return max_2nd.key;
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example input that returns an incorrect value? [9, 1, 2] returns 2 to me.

Comment: This is the test code I was given:public static void test2ndMax() {
  String result;
  String answers[] = { null, null, "E", "C", "S", "U", "H", "X", "P", "X" };  
  
  for (int i = 0; i < cases.length; i++) {
   result = newLinkedList(i).secondMaxKey();
   if (result == null ? answers[i] != null : !result.equals(answers[i])) {
    wrongResult(i, result);
   }
  }
 }

Comment: Output from Compiler: Testing secondMax
Returned incorrect value A for case 3
Returned incorrect value A for case 4
Returned incorrect value K for case 6
Returned incorrect value H for case 7
Returned incorrect value K for case 8
Done testing secondMax...some tests failed!

Comment: I think this test code only includes the correct answers. Do you have the content of the 'cases' variable?

Comment: Also, what should happen if the input array has a duplicate max value? For example: ["A", "B" "C", "C"]. Should we return "B" or "C"?

Comment: Hi please check the main post I added the full test code. I believe the answer to your question would be B.

Comment: Ok I think I see. They want you to compare the values of the Nodes, not their keys. Please see my edited answer (not sure what the 'value' attribute name is)

Comment: I tried this but I get the error "The operation > is invalid for the argument types Value, Value" This error is on the line where you compare x.val >max.val. perhaps i need to use this method?    public Value get(Key key) {
        if (key == null) throw new NullPointerException("argument to get() is null"); 
        for (Node x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
            if (key.equals(x.key))
                return x.val;
        }
        return null;
    }

Comment: Not sure how you can compare "Value" objects together. You might need to use "compareTo" (see my edit)

Comment: Tried that and it says the method compareTo(Value) is undefined for the type Value

Comment: Do you have some kind of documentation for the `Value` class? You just need to find a way to compare them.

Comment: nvm i figured out both questions!

Answer (score 0):

This helps you ,

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        List l=new ArrayList();
        l.add(9);
        l.add(1);
        l.add(2);

        int max2=max_2nd(l);
        System.out.println(max2);
    }
    private static int max_2nd(List l) {

        Set s= new HashSet(l);
        s.remove(Collections.max(s));
        int i =(int)Collections.max(s);
        return i;

    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I cannot use this code it has many things i haven't learned and outside libraries from class

Answer (score 0):

Please Check below logic. I have checked with your code here and it returns second maximum (Edited as per LinkedListST in the question)

```
   public Key secondMaxKey () {
    Node max = first;
    Node max_2nd = null;
    Node temp = null;

    if (size() < 2) {
        return null;
    }

    for (Node x = first.next; x != null; x = x.next) {
        if (x.key.compareTo(max.key)>0) {
            temp = max;
            max = x;
            if(temp.key.compareTo(max_2nd.key)>0)
            {
                max_2nd=temp;
            }

        } else if (max_2nd == null || x.key.compareTo(max_2nd.key) > 0) {
            max_2nd = x;
        }
    }

    return max_2nd.key;
}
```

for example

```
{9,1,2}
Loop 1 (x=1) : max =9 max_2 =0 x=1 After loop max = 9 max_2 = 1
Loop 2 (x=2) : max =9 max_2 =1 x=2 After loop max = 9 max_2 = 2
```